# Why is DevDemon's Subscriptions not setting an expiry during the subscription process?

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

I am currently running EE 2.9.2 and Subscriptions 1.6.0 with a Stripe payment gateway.

Currently, I am running a live test with a $1 subscription plan with an interval of every 1 day for a max cycles of 1. In other words, a 1 day plan. Autorenew is OFF. Problem is simple: when I subscribe (with member registration allowed), the expiration date is not generated. It appears as NULL in the Db.

This was occurring earlier, as well, when I was running in TEST mode (using a member assigned as a test user in the Subscriptions CP). That test used a 1 year, non-renewing plan.

Everything else appears to be working correctly. Member is registered, moved to the proper member group, logged in on subscribe, stripe js (verifying...) works, payment is being processed, and subscription is recorded in CP. Everything but the expiry date.

My template follows the samples given fairly closely:

```
{exp:subs:subscribe
    register_member="yes"
    plan="{segment_3}"
    user_amount="{stash:v_user_amount}"
    payment_method="stripe"
    return="members/confirm-new/%SUBS_HASH%"
}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
    <input type="hidden" class="stripe_public_key" value="[...]">
    <input type="hidden" name="card_token" class="stripe_token">

    ...form fields..

    <script src="https://[domain]/js/stripe.js"></script>
{/exp:subs:subscribe}
```

Other add-ons being used:

- Assets
- Channel Videos
- Freeform Pro
- Google Maps for EE
- Stash, IfElse, Switchee
- SuperSearch
- User
- Wygwam

Comment: Did you figure this out? Apparently they fixed this bug and I am waiting for them to send me their updated code as its not released on their site yet

Comment: I am seeing this issue as well.